# Torch Tensor with same shape but different storage size

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm working on GANs model, the generator creates a tensor with size `(3,128,128)` which I dumped with the pseudo-code

```py
import torch
image = Generator(noise).clone()
tensor = image[0].detach().cpu()
torch.save(tensor, save_path)
```

The problem is that tensor costs more storage than the same tensor size, even they have the same `shape` and `dtype`

```
>>> import sys
>>> import torch
>>> tensor = tensor.load(save_path)
>>> rand_t = torch.randn(tensor.shape)
>>> print(tensor.shape, rand_t.shape)
torch.Size([3, 128, 128]) torch.Size([3, 128, 128])
>>> print(tensor.dtype, rand_t.dtype)
torch.float32 torch.float32
>>> print(sys.getsizeof(tensor.storage()))
9830472
>>> print(sys.getsizeof(rand_t.storage()))
196680
```

I tried to dump those tensors, the output from the generator took `9.2MB` and the random tensor took `197.4kB`. I did read the pytorch's documents but found nothing. Please help me to figure out what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like extracting a sub-tensor directly from the original will bring the whole container with it. The function `.clone()` can solve it. Example:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import torch
>>> tensor = torch.randn(10,3,128,128)
>>> sys.getsizeof(tensor.storage())
1966144
>>> sub1 = tensor[0]
>>> sub1.shape
torch.Size([3, 128, 128])
>>> sys.getsizeof(sub1.storage())
1966144
>>> sub2 = tensor[0].clone()
>>> sub2.shape
torch.Size([3, 128, 128])
>>> sys.getsizeof(sub2.storage())
196672
```

Therefore, in my case, cloning the image individually should solve the problem:

```py
import torch
image = Generator(noise).clone() 
tensor = image[0].detach().clone().cpu() # using clone()
torch.save(tensor, save_path)
```